# import multi-value from csv into Field Collections

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a simple csv file with 3 columns: NID|Key|List where NID is the node id and Key was the unique value used to add field collections to the respective node. "List" is a multi-value field separated by ";".

```
Example (csv file):
NID,Key,List
1,2,text1;text2;text3
1,3,text4;text4
2,123,text1
...
```

*Field collection* has an *entity reference* field to a *taxonomy* plus other fields.

```
Field Collections:
Field1: text;
Field2: Term Reference;
Field3: Entity Reference; <-- importer/tamper not working!
...
```

The *field collection* fields were mapped correctly, except for the field that was an *entity reference* to a taxonomy. I configured *Feeds Tamper* and the *Field Collection Feeds* module but nothing was imported.

Does anyone has experience importing a multi-value field from a csv file into an *entity reference* field within a *field collection*?

Answer (score 0):

Using the same feeds importer configuration but instead of importing with the standalone form, it worked once it was moved to a content type form. If a content type is selected a source is imported by creating a node of that content type.